# lightningchart js bar chart tooltip different values then original values

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I tried to follow this example online,

https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-1400-histogramGaussian.html?isList=true

I am curious about if there is a way to change the tooltip values to show different information.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No offense, but it is quite easy to spot "Range" and "Amount of values" in the example code which you linked - maybe have a quick look and Ctrl+F before opening a thread?

[image]